# creating arrays in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I  need to make the random array print, and it does, &  then i need to make the code sort my random array and print that.
I think, i have missed something out on the  code,

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab5
{   
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
     Random r = new Random();
     int[]arr = new int[5];

     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {
       arr[i] = Math.abs(r.nextInt()%255) +1;
       System.out.print(arr[i] + "\t");
      }
     System.out.println();
}

public static void ShowArray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
System.out.println(array.get(i));

System.out.println("Sort A: ");
ArrayList<Integer> sortedArrayA = ThreeSorts.SortA(array);
ShowArray(sortedArrayA);
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you having problems?

Comment: Actually I think that @Mikeb may be right. Your array seems to be being sorted in the ShowArray function and I don't see a call to it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int[]arr = new int[5];

for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    arr[i] = Math.abs(r.nextInt()%255) +1;
    System.out.print(arr[i] + "\t");
}

System.out.println();
Arrays.sort(arr);
for(int item: arr)
    System.out.println(item);
```

Comment: thanks for this it helps me to sort the data but i am calling the sort method from a different class called ThreeSorts.java so how would i use the sort method on there?

Answer (score 0):

Retrace your execution - does the code that you wrote run?

Don't forget that code in a function only runs when the function is called.

Comment: yes the first part of the code runs, and manages to generate random numbers, i just cant get the sort code to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following code may give you some useful hints:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[] {3,4,65,1,43};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
 }
```

Notes:

- I skip the part related to generating random integer, because you have it
- to print an array you may use `Arrays.toString()`
- to sort an array you may use `Arrays.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

In method main you must add ShowArray(arg).

Answer (score 0):

As @Mikeb and @Belinda point out, ShowArray is not being called.  Furthermore, it is an infinitely recursive function, as it calls itself without a base case to terminate; perhaps you meant to put some of the lines in the main method?  I corrected the indentation on your code so as to see this better.